# Concatenate all list content in one string in C#

Tags: c#, list

How do I concatenate all content of a list in one string in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma "izing" a list of items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368551/comma-izing-a-list-of-items)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Searching for this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(); // { "This ", "is ", "your ", "string!"};
list.Add("This ");
list.Add("is ");
list.Add("your ");
list.Add("string!");

string concat = string.Join(" ", list.ToArray());
```

Comment: how can I separate between them by space ?

Comment: `string.Join(" ", list.ToArray());`

Comment: Not sure you need the ToArray() part anymore (.NET 4): String.Join() seems to have overloads for List<string> and List<int>.

Comment: @EdGraham In fact, the overload is for IEnumerable<T> and there's a specific one for IEnumerable<string>

Comment: missing a space after "string!"

Comment: ^ Wrong way around ... all those other trailing spaces should be removed.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Aggregate function to concatenate all items of a list.

The following is the example to concatenate all the items of a list with comma ","

```
string s = list.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j).ToString();
```

Comment: Note: this yields an exception when the list has zero elements.

Answer (score 9):

If you have some properties within your objects and want to do some more formatting there, then using LINQ,

```
var output = string.Join(" ", list.Select(t => t.Prop1 + " " + t.Prop2));
```

This will put a space in between each of the properties of your objects and a space in between each object as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to transform your list elements while joining, you can use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
string.Join(", ", mylist.Select(z => MyMethod(z)));
```

Example:

```
IEnumerable<string> mylist = new List<string>() {"my", "cool", "list"};
string joined = string.Join(", ", mylist.Select(z => MyMethod(z)));


public string MyMethod(string arg)
{
    return arg.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Why it was -1? Any reason?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution with StringBuilder:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        strings.ForEach(s => sb.Append(s));
        var combinedList = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    List<String> myStrings = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
    StringBuilder concatenatedString = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (String myString in myStrings)
    {
        concatenatedString.Append(myString);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(concatenatedString.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter)
{
    string d = String.Empty;
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        result.Append(d).Append(item.ToString());
        d = delimiter;
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

And an overload for optional better string conversion of individual values:

```
public static string ToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter, Func<T, string> toString)
{
    string d = String.Empty;
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        result.Append(d).Append(toString(item));
        d = delimiter;
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that separates elements using two spaces implemented using LINQ:

```
var s = list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, current) => 
  sb.AppendFormat("{0}  ", current)).ToString();
```

The `Aggregate` method passes the `StringBuilder` (as `sb`) with the current element of the list (as `current`) to the lambda expression which can do anything it needs - for example append the current string from the list to the `StringBuilder` using some formatting specified in the lambda expression body.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. `string.Join` does it all.

Comment: @Matt: You're right - it allows you to specify a separator (I forgot about that), but in some cases, you may still need more powerful solution.

Comment: Yeah, true. And the more LINQ gets exposed the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.AllFacilityId = request.FacilityIdList.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j);
```