# Create user-readable, display-friendly formatted string from List<string>

Tags: c#, string

I know several questions have been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799446/275643) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/368551/275643) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205555/275643) about how to create a comma delimited string from a list. I'm looking for help on something slightly different.

What I would like to do is create a display-friendly human-readable string from a `List<string>` that reads like *"A, B and C are invalid values"*. The grammar and format of the string should change based on the number of items in the list. The list could contain any number of items.

**For example:**

```
List<string> myString = new List<string>() { "Scooby", "Dooby", "Doo" };
// Should return "Scooby, Dooby and Doo are invalid values."

List<string> myString = new List<string>() { "Scooby", "Dooby" };
// Should return "Scooby and Dooby are invalid values."

List<string> myString = new List<string>() { "Scooby" };
// Should return "Scooby is an invalid value."
```

**Here's what I've done so far:**

```
string userMessage = "";
foreach(string invalidValue in invalidValues)
{
  userMessage = " " + userMessage + invalidValue + ",";
}

// Remove the trailing comma
userMessage = userMessage.Substring(0, userMessage.LastIndexOf(','));

if (invalidValues.Count > 1)
{
  int lastCommaLocation = userMessage.LastIndexOf(',');
  userMessage = userMessage.Substring(0, lastCommaLocation) + " and " + userMessage.Substring(lastCommaLocation + 1) + " are invalid values.";
}
else 
{
  userMessage = userMessage + " is an invalid value.";
}
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can check how is the Rails [Array#to_sentence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence) is implemented...

Comment: I had a hard time finding exactly this thing, using Google. I'm glad you asked it, even so long ago, and even gladder someone gave a nice succinct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static string FormatList(List<string> invalidItems)
{
    if(invalidItems.Count == 0) return string.Empty;
    else if(invalidItems.Count == 1) return string.Format("{0} is an invalid value", invalidItems[0]);
    else return string.Format("{0} and {1} are invalid values", string.Join(", ", invalidItems.Take(invalidItems.Count - 1)), invalidItems.Last());
}
```

Comment: Great answer. This is why I love Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Heavily indebted to @Lee in his other answer, here's a much-expanded version of his method. It allows you to specify a beginning text and/or an ending text, and it uses the Oxford comma, the omission of which, as we all know, once had catastrophic results for the plaintiff in a lawsuit... but if you hate the darn thing you can just remove it from the method as written.

```
        public static string GrammaticallyCorrectStringFrom(List<string> items, string prefaceTextWithNoSpaceAtEnd, string endingTextWithoutPeriod)
    {
        var returnString = string.Empty;
        if (items.Count != 0)
        {
            returnString = prefaceTextWithNoSpaceAtEnd + " ";
        }
        if (items.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += string.Format("{0}", items[0]);
        }
        else if (items.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString += items[0] + " and " + items[1];
        }
        else if (items.Count > 2)
        {
            //remove the comma in the string.Format part if you're an anti-Oxford type
            returnString += string.Format("{0}, and {1}", string.Join(", ", items.Take(items.Count - 1)), items.Last());
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnString) == false)
        {
            returnString += endingTextWithoutPeriod + ".";
        }           
        return returnString;
    }
```

There's probably a better, less-verbose way to do the same thing, but this is working for me, and it's hard to argue with results. Actually I guess it isn't, here, but still... Anyway, anyone with a fire to improve this is welcome to.